# jQuery getting selected item of dynamic listview

Tags: listview, jquery-mobile, dynamic, selecteditem

I am generating a dynamic collapsible-set with listViews using XML data. It's generated correctly, but I need a click/touch event to display some data before it goes to another page. Here is my code:

```
$("#dvAccordion").empty();
var outdiv = $('<div data-role="collapsible-set"></div>');
$(strXML).find('Category').each(function(){
    var colldiv = $('<div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true"></div>');
    colldiv.append('<h3>' + $(this).find('Category_Name').text() + '</h3>');    
    var uldiv = $('<ul  data-role="listview" data-inset="false"></ul>');
    colldiv.append(uldiv);
    //
    $(this).find('Menu_Item').each(function(){
        var sItemName = $(this).find('item_name').text() ;
        uldiv.append('<li data-name="baby"><a href="menu.html" rel="external">' + sItemName + '</a></li>');                         
    });
    //
    //$('#dvAccordion').listview('refresh');
    //
    outdiv.append(colldiv);
    outdiv.appendTo('#dvAccordion');
});
//$('#dvAccordion [data-role=collapsible-set]').collapsibleset();
//$('#dvAccordion').collapsibleset();
//$('#dvAccordion').collapsibleset('refresh');

$('#dvAccordion').trigger('create');
```

I am adding an eventListener on page load like this:

```
$('#dvAccordion ul').children('li').bind('vclick', function(e) {
alert('Selected Name=' + $(this).attr('data-name'));
});
```

This bind code works fine if it's for a static collapsible-set of HTML. It shows an alert before moving to 'menu.html'. But for my dynamic set it moves to 'menu.html' without any alert. Please help.

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle with your created dynamic lists?

Comment: @yeyene sure I'll do that.

Comment: Here is the jsFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/yesprasoon/MvcHm/. Static item returns id, but dynamic doesn't.

Comment: check my answer in answer section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call the function `generateDynamicAccordion();` first.

DEMO here http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/MvcHm/9/

## JQUERY

```
    generateDynamicAccordion();    
    $('#dvDynamic_selectId ul').children('li').bind('vclick', function(e) {
        var sId = $(this).attr('data-id');
        alert('Selected id=' + sId);
    }); 
    //
    $('#dvStatic_selectId ul').children('li').bind('vclick', function(e) {
        var sId = $(this).attr('data-id');
        alert('Selected id=' + sId);
    });
```